# Unable to generate SSDL after adding Cascade Delete

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to model (with designer) this situation:
I have a ***Client*** (abstract) and two derived entities: **Private** and **Public**.
Moreover I've an **Addresses** and an **Orders** entities.
The Private *has* 1 "permanent address" property, the Public, *has* 1 "Registered address" property.
I modelled this like:

> Private(0..1)->(1)Addresses and Public(0..1)->(1)Addresses

Now, *each* Client, can have *more* orders. 1 Order *has* a shipping address:

> Client(1)->(*)Orders
>   Orders(0..1)->(1)Addresses

All the addresses are defined as Navigation properties.

If I build the model now, it works, but when I delete a client from context, in my address table remain the addresses.
So I tried to add a END1 Cascade Delete for each connection to address entity.

On building I get this errors refferring connections between address related entities:

> The SSDL generated by the activity called 'CsdlToSsdlAndMslActivity' is not valid and has the following errors:
>   End '{0}' on relationship '{1}' cannot have operation specified since its multiplicity is '*'. Operations cannot be specified on ends with multiplicity '*'.

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot cascade on delete when the aggregated entity is deleted. Make sure you put the `Cascade` on the correct end, i.e. the end **which represents the parent/owning** entity.

In your case, I would try to put the `Cascade` on `End2` instead.